# Crear array con datos de fecha y hora en php

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, array

Tengo que crear un array en PHP con información que viene desde un json.

Actualmente tengo mi código que crea un array donde guarda la fecha "10-15-2018" con su cantidad de mensajes totales.

Ahora necesito modificar mi array para poder capturar el día con su mensajes totales, mensajes enviados y mensajes recibidos.

Dentro del mismo array que guarde las horas con sus mensajes totales, mensajes enviados y mensajes recibidos.

El problema es que no logro poder hacerlo ya que no se como comenzar a hacerlo. alguien me puede guiar como hacerlo.

Si encuentra el día o la hora en el array que aumente la cantidad en uno en mensajes totales, mensajes enviados y mensajes recibidos según lo encuentre.

En el json viene  "type": que es "IN" que son mensajes de entrada y "OUT" mensajes de salida y `creation_date` que es la fecha cuando se envía o recibe un mensaje.

**este es mi código actual :**

```
public function Informe_Completo(Request $request)
{

    $empresa = self::Empresa_Citrup();

    $resul = self::Api_Extrae_Mensajes($empresa);

    $in = 0;

    $out = 0;

    $total = 0;

    $fecha = array();

    $dias = array();

    foreach($resul as $item) 
    {

        $date = date_create($item->creation_date, timezone_open(Config::get('constants.zona_horaria')));
                        // Buenos Aires
        date_timezone_set($date, timezone_open($empresa->zona_horaria)); 

        $newDate = $date->format('d-m-Y G:i:s');

        if ($this->check_in_range($request->input('from'), $request->input('to'), $newDate))
        {

            // ------------ resultados generales-------------//
            $total++; //total mensajes 

            //mensajes enviado
            if($item->type == 'IN'){

            $in++; // total mensajes de salida


            }else{

                $out++; //totak de mensjaes de entrada

            }

            //-------------------------------------------// 

            //--------contar mensajes por dia-------------//
            $fecha[]  = $date->format('Y-m-d');

            $hora[]  = $date->format('G:i:s');

            $fecha[] = 1;

            foreach($fecha as $value)
            {
                if(isset($dias[$value]))
                {

                    // si ya existe, le añadimos uno
                    $dias[$value]+=1;

                }else{
                    // si no existe lo añadimos al array
                    $dias[$value]=1;

                }
            }

            unset($fecha);//vaciamos el array
            //---------------------------------------------//

        }
    }

    // uasort($dias, [$this, 'Ordenar_Array']);   
    unset($dias['1']);

    // var_dump($dias); exit;
    // return array($total, $in, $out, $dias);

    return view('informe/informe_general')
                ->with('total', $total)
                ->with('in', $in)
                ->with('out', $out)
                ->with('dias', $dias);
}
```

**El archivo json:**

```
[{ 
    "id": "7797", 
    "number": "[YOUR NUMBER]", 
    "from": "[FROM NUMBER]", 
    "to": "[TO NUMBER]", 
    "type": "IN", 
    "text": "I need to know your pricing list", 
    "creation_date": "2017-03-18 14:49:23" 
    "process_date": "2017-03-18 14:49:23",
    "custom_data": null
}, 
{ 
    "id": "7798", 
    "number": "[YOUR NUMBER]", 
    "from": "[FROM NUMBER]", 
    "to": "[TO NUMBER]", 
    "type": "OUT",  
    "text": "Our pricing list is in our Web site http://my.beautiful-site.com!", 
    "creation_date": "2017-03-18 14:51:08" 
    "process_date": "2017-03-18 14:51:15",
    "custom_data": "1234"
},
```

**Esto es lo que quiero conseguir:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. No le veo mucha lógica a *lo que quieres conseguir*... Sólo veo una redundancia asombrosa de datos que se repiten una y otra vez. O algo anda mal en la lógica que estás siguiendo, o es que no has sabido explicar bien lo que quieres.

Comment: Hola. Tengo un sistema de chat donde varios agentes atienden los chat.
<br>
Lo que quiero hacer es mostrar un reporte filtrado por fechas donde se visualise los dias con sus mensajes totales, enviado y recibidos.<br>
<br>
Tambien debo mostrar las horas de los dias en donde tambien debo mostrar&nbsp; sus mensajes totales, enviado y recibidos por hora.<br>
<br>
No se si me explico.<br>
<br>
Son muchos registros.

Answer (score 0):

Creo entender lo que quieres. Partiendo del JSON original, deberías crear una matriz preliminar, con los datos "en bruto", con json_decode(). Luego, es cuestión de recorrerla, y comprobar si existen claves con cada fecha y hora, en una matriz, digamos, procesada.

El siguiente código te muestra lo que sugiero:

```
<?php
    $datosOriginales = <<<JSON
        [{
            "id": "7797",
            "number": 949493394,
            "from": 944939,
            "to": 494030303030,
            "type": "IN",
            "text": "Texto de prueba",
            "creation_date": "2017-03-18 14:49:23",
            "process_date": "2017-03-18 14:49:23",
            "custom_data": null
        },
        {
            "id": "4988",
            "number": 54455,
            "from": 944939,
            "to": 5666589,
            "type": "OUT",
            "text": "Texto de prueba",
            "creation_date": "2018-04-18 08:49:23",
            "process_date": "2018-04-18 08:49:23",
            "custom_data": null
        }]      
JSON;

    $matrizOriginal = json_decode($datosOriginales, true);
    $matrizProcesada = [];
    foreach ($matrizOriginal as $item) {
        $fecha = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($item["creation_date"]));
        if (!array_key_exists($fecha, $matrizProcesada)) {
            $matrizProcesada[$fecha] = [];
        }
        $hora = date("H", strtotime($item["creation_date"])).":00";
        if (!array_key_exists($hora, $matrizProcesada[$fecha])) {
            $matrizProcesada[$fecha][$hora] = [
                "totales"=>0,
                "IN"=>0,
                "OUT"=>0
            ];
        }
        $matrizProcesada[$fecha][$hora]["totales"] ++;
        if ($item["type"] == "IN") {
            $matrizProcesada[$fecha][$hora]["IN"] ++;
        } else {
            $matrizProcesada[$fecha][$hora]["OUT"] ++;
        }
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($matrizOriginal, $matrizProcesada);
    echo "</pre>";

?>
```

Si he entendido tu pregunta, ese código te puede resolver el tema. Si no es eso a lo que te referías, por favor, especifica un poco más, y trataré de ayudarte.

PD. Como sugerencia, los textos de la matriz que buscas y del JSON del que partes, ponlos como texto, no como imágenes. Así es más fácil trabajarlo.